# Increase DIV height with scrolldown up to a limit

Tags: jquery

In a page with vertically stacked sections, one of these sections contains a jquery accordion.

[image: example]

The first accordion UL (green in picture) is `$(window).height()-ConstantPixels`, so that the accordion takes 100% of the available height. (red box represents browser window).
Which means that sometimes a part of it will ne hidden.

So what i'm trying to accomplish is to start increasing the green UL's height when scrolling down, until all green content is visible. Any suggestions?
thank you

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why not let the Green box take the height of the content by default instead of setting the height to window height - pixels?

Comment: Agreed. The only reason is because they asked me to do so - if possible.

Comment: It is possible, although you might want to push back and tell them it is not needed or just understand exactly why would they need it. Anyway, check my answer below it might point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you share some code I probably can help better, but here's the general idea.

You can listen to the scroll event of the browser, and set the height dynamically for that specific div. Something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var currentHeight = $('#greendiv').height();
    $('#greendiv').height(currentHeight + $(document).scrollTop());
});
```

Something like that. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
var no=1,new= $('#div').height();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if(no==1)
    {
        if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
            no=2;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "request.php",
                data: datas,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                   $('#div').height($(document).height()+new);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much but i don't quite understand it yet. Can you pls explain line 1? (i suspect there's a typo?)

Comment: there is no typo. it is just variable declaration... no=1 means its increase the heigth of div only one time when scroll down....